# Display existing individual data in placeholder

Tags: placeholder

Im using HTML 5 placeholder and i was wondering if it would be possible that the placeholder display the existing current data (extracted from database).

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="current_email" placeholder="HERE I WOULD LIKE THE USER's CURRENT EMAIL TO BE DISPLAYED"value="" />
```

Is there any easy way to do this ? (i'm quite new to html5 / php / js / jquery)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your placeholder with

```
placeholder="<?php echo $user['mail']; ?>"
```

By the way, $user['mail'] in an exemple, replace it with whatever your variable is.

This is some very basic use of HTML / PhP, before asking more questions like this, you should give a look at some tutorials, it will be quicker

Comment: Thank you. I've been searching how to do this for 2 hours now without any success. tries several options. i think the problem is that the user mail isn't stored in the session but rather in the database. it may require an SQL query which i dont mind writing, i just dont know how to link it.

Comment: One more time, you should check for tutorials such as "How to create a simple news page", "How to create a forum" in Php. Seems like you're missing some concepts and you'll waste so much time searching for answers everytime a line has a problem.

Comment: Yes you are of course correct. however i need to finish this feature by this eve which doesn't allow too much time to learn php html and js from scratch. BTW, using your suggestion, the placeholder displays the code line as text. there doesn't seem to be any understanding that the code inserted is php.

Comment: You file has to be `file.php`, not `file.html` so that the server can interpret the PhP code

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do something like this ?

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="current_email" placeholder="<?=$var?>"value="" />
```

It works for me in javascript at least.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. I've tried your option however no success. Is there any way perhaps to redirect to a php file where i can write a database query and echo the response ?